# I want to fetch time column from mysql database and to compare with current time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch time column from mysql database and to compare with current time. 
It should execute only if it matches with the current time.

Please tell me a MySql query or php code to do this.

I am new to php.

[image]

Comment: *Please tell me a MySql query or php code to do this* No. Start Research by your own and come back with specific problems

Comment: I did it. But it didnt help

Comment: Show what you tried and how it didn't met your expectations then.

Comment: I tried like this timings> '".$created1."' and timings< '".$created1.where $created1=date('H:i:s');

Comment: PLease help me.Atleast give a clue

Comment: You can see in the table- I have Hyphen and or symbol

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  <?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "myDB";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 
  $today = date("h:i a")
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, ' ', 2) = '".$today."'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // execute you code
  } else {

  }

  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: **Updated Code**

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "myDB";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 
  $today = date("h:i a")
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE time = $today";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // execute you code
  } else {

  }

  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Comment: Can I have the datatype of time column, which you are using

Comment: What is the logic for your symbols?